# Add to text option to reveal/hide

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

The scrolling of the page turns into torment :) I would like to make it so that the information would initially be hidden (for example, only the first couple of lines, and then the "more" button. By clicking on which you can open the entire text. And, accordingly, at the end text less button to hide the text back to its original state.
https://www.quora.com/Is-there-a-site-where-you-can-type-in-a-long-text-then-the-site-will-try-to-shorten-the-text-for-you-by-reformatting-the-text-in-different-ways).

```
export default function PocketDataResponse({ firestore, urlParams }) {
    const recordRef = firestore
        .collection("devices").doc(urlParams.deviceId)
        .collection("records").doc(urlParams.recordId)

    const record = useRecord(recordRef)

    return (
        record ?
            <TableContainer sx={styles.TableContainer}>
                Body: {record.response.body} <br></br>  // Here I would like to do what would hide and reveal the text
                Headers: {record.response.headers.toString()} <br></br>
                
                
            </TableContainer>
            : <Typography> Record not found </Typography>
    );
}
```

This function is responsible for getting the data from the database (in my case, it is a firestore) and displaying it on the page (in fact, this component is passed to me in two more components, but this does not matter for solving this problem).

Tell me, how can I display the response body as hidden text?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a state variable `showFullText` to handle how the text is displayed.
If `false` it will display only a part of the response:

```
export default function PocketDataResponse({ firestore, urlParams }) {
  const recordRef = firestore
    .collection('devices')
    .doc(urlParams.deviceId)
    .collection('records')
    .doc(urlParams.recordId);

  const record = useRecord(recordRef);

  const [showFullText, setShowFullText] = useState(false);

  const truncateText = (str, len) => {
    if (str.length < len) return str;
    return str.substring(0, len) + '...';
  };

  return record ? (
    <TableContainer sx={styles.TableContainer}>
      Body: {showFullText ? record.response.body : truncateText(record.response.body, 100)} <br></br> 
      <button type='button' onClick={() => setShowFullText(prev => !prev)}>{showFullText ? 'Show less' : 'Show more'}</button>
      Headers: {record.response.headers.toString()} <br></br>
    </TableContainer>
  ) : (
    <Typography> Record not found </Typography>
  );
}
```